# spreadsheet excel writer 9.2

Tags: php, mysql

I am using spreadsheet_excel_writer(9.2) to download an excel file from a mysql (4.1.22) database. I have done this successfully on the same server, and this code is very similar, but on this occasion it isn't working. I get an excel file that has the data in it but all in one cell with all sorts of characters intermingled. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? I have been making alterations and re-testing for days now. I would really appreciate it if someone could spot something that I am not seeing.

```
   <?php
require_once "/home/cloudare/php/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php";
// Create workbook
$workbook =& new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
// sending HTTP headers
$workbook->send('registration.xls');
// Create worksheet
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('Registration Worksheet');

// Add DB connection script here
include("dbinfo.inc.php");
include("functions.inc.php");
$from=$_POST['from'];
$to=$_POST['to'];
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE  date BETWEEN  '$from'  AND  '$to'" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
//$result = do_query($query,__LINE__);

// Loop through the data, adding it to the sheet

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $array[] = $row; 
    extract($row);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,0,$id);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,1,$name);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,2,$last);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,3,$title);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,4,$company);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,5,$phone);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,6,$mobile);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,7,$email);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,8,$cloud);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,9,$participant);
    $worksheet->write($currentRow,10,$date);
    // Remember Excel starts counting rows from #1!
    $excelRow = $currentRow + 1;
    $currentRow++;
}

$workbook->close();
?>
```

This is the resultant worksheet:

> ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ

þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

> s@Gert
>   MrClann
>   Credogert@clanncredo.ie
>    2011-06-17°s@Jim
>   MaherDirectorTrigraph
>   01-6390050087-6261422jim@trigraph.ieð?
>
> 2011-06-17Às@MichaelMcKennaPrincipal
>   Consultant
>   SmartCloud@ìÌ˜TBmmckenna@smartcloud.ieð?
>
> 2011-06-17Ðs@LiamConnolly
>   ConsultantCapricornVentis6¦ÊA#liam.connolly@capventis.comð?
>
> 2011-06-17às@MinhajShaikh
>   MrNCIapnaminhaj@hotmail.comð?
>    2011-06-17> ¶ Root
>   Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Comment: @yes123: it's required for S_E_W. It's an old library.

Comment: @Marc: actually I think it depends on which PHP version it runs. No need for it if he is using 5.3+

Answer (score 1):

S_E_W is deadware. You should switch to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) at some point, especially if you want support for something newer than BIFF 5.0 files (Excel 5.0).

Check that your query is working correctly and produces a proper $row. And try to avoid `extract()` like the plague. It's almost as horrible an idea as `register_globals` was and lets you reproduce the exact same problems that register_globals caused in the first place. It's not much more work to type out `$row['id']`, `$row['name']` etc..., and saves you the annoyance of overwriting other variables you were using for other purposes BEFORE doing the extract() call.

Comment: Hi Marc B, thanks for that. I tried replacing my loop omitting the extract() but got exactly the same result. I think it may be because I am on Excel 2003 and I get the message,"this file is not in a recognizable format". I think I will try PHPExcel, as you suggest. Does it work for Excel 2003?

Comment: DOn't open the file directly in excel. Download it instead, and view it in a text editor. Perhaps there's some PHP errors/warnings getting output as well causing excel to think the file's corrupted. And yeah, PHPExcel can handle the latest .xls and .xlsx formats.